# How can I make my website work on any resolution

Tags: html, css

I have recently created a website for our school and it was great. However, when I tested it to another laptop, the contents of my website was a mess like they are not in their exact places. Some example of my code:

```
#headText {
color: #1f8e1c;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-top: 1%;
}

#label_desc {
color: #1f8e1c;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-top: 1%;
}
```

This makes the "headText" and "label_desc" in the center of my site, but when I tested it to another laptop, the *headtext and label_desc* seems to appear on different places.

On the other hand, when I zoom in my website (on my laptop), the contents still moves and it disarranged itself unlike most websites when you zoom in, the contents gets bigger and still stays in their proper places.

Can you please help me? I really need it so badly.

## UPDATE

Thanks to *hakre*, what I meant was **screen-size**, not *resolution*.

## UPDATE 2

To summarize my problem -> http://postimg.org/image/r1hs6i3kb/

Comment: Does you website works with *several* browsers (firefox, chrome, opera, ...) ? What framework do you use?

Comment: Centering works within a parent-element with `text-align: center` then having he child-element a width and more importantly the left and right margin set to `auto` so that the browser can actually center it. Otherwise you're aligning to the left.

Comment: I think it is not a case with different systems rather different browsers. you have to dissect and treat individual incompatibilities.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes it works on any browsers.. I think it's in the resolution where every laptop/computer has different ones..

Comment: @hakre Yes I tried it but instead it placed itself on the left side..

Comment: @DKReigns: You're perhaps not yet that fluent with CSS. I  added you an answer and there is also a good book where you can fetch what you need from: http://www.cssdesignpatterns.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a left margin:

```
margin-left: 20%;
```

Each browser will do this left margin, there-fore not centering the element *but* aligning it to the left.

Instead set left and right margin to `auto` and a width (suggestable) smaller than 100% to show the effect:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    center-me :)
  </div>
</div>


#parent {}

#child {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 1% auto 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hRsLr/

This is independent to *resolution*. Resolution is about how many pixels there are per the square centimeter. Why you most likely mean is *screen-size* which is related, but different. More precisely, you mean the size available in the browsers view-port, that is the area where the website is rendered into.

Comment: Thanks man, it helps. I just googled everything and still didn't find an answer but got a clue though, something called "max-width/min-width"... I tried it though but the result was horrible. I watch several examples and it worked on them -- their (example) buttons stays in place whether you zoom in or zoom out just like facebook.com etc.. mine is when i zoom in or zoom out the buttons keeps staying inside the display and disarranged themselves :(

Comment: @DKReigns: When I do such design I normally create sample static HTML files containing all elements and having the CSS in there. Then I test that with different browser sizes and zooms how it behaves. It's best done step-by step, I also put that under version control so I can better debug it. When done, I can re-use the HTML and CSS within the application.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Here's the problem in a picture to make it easy to understand :) http://postimg.org/image/r1hs6i3kb/